# Como puedo "Reiniciar" una secuencia de números PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

actualmente me encuentro trabajando en un modulo donde existen "Kits" estos kits tienen materiales dentro pero lo que quiero es que al borrar por ejemplo el kit 3, se recorran los demás y el "4" cambie a 3, cabe resaltar que estos kits tienen un campo en la base de datos que indica el número de kit pero no se me ocurre una manera de poder actualizar todos los datos dentro del kit sin id para que estos al mismo tiempo cambien a otro numero de kit, alguna idea de lo que podría hacer???

aqui debajo adjunto mi tabla aunque pues esta funciona bien pero la dejo para dar un poco de contexto, soy algo nuevo asi que no se me ocurre una solucion rápida

```
<?PHP
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT `pieza` AS pieza, `desripcion` AS descripcion, `cantidad` AS cantidad, `kit` AS kit, `id_modelo` AS id_modelo, `id` AS id_kit, `modelo` AS modelo, `id_pieza` AS id_pieza FROM `kit` WHERE `modelo` = '$kit' ORDER BY `kit` ASC");
$tmp = null;
$colheads = ['Pieza', 'Descripcion', 'Cantidad', 'Acción'];
$colo = ['kit:'];
$contador=1;
        // echo"SELECT `pieza` AS pieza, `desripcion` AS descripcion, `cantidad` AS cantidad, `kit` AS kit, `id_modelo` AS id_modelo, `id` AS id_kit, `modelo` AS modelo, `id_pieza` AS id_pieza FROM `kit` WHERE `modelo` = '$kit' ORDER BY `kit` ASC";
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {  // no produzca más elementos por fila de los necesarios
    if ($tmp != $row['kit']) {  // Determina si existe un nuevo grupo / kit value
        if ($tmp !== null) {
            echo '</table></br></br></br>';  // Cierra la tabla previa
        }
        echo '<table style=width:1000px;><tr style=width:20px;><th>', implode('</th><th>', $colo), ' ', $row['kit'], '</th></tr></table>';
        echo $contador++;
        // Inicia una nueva tabla y añade encabezados
        echo '</br>';
        echo '<table border=1 style=width:1000px;><tr align=center><th>', implode('</th><th>', $colheads), '</th></tr>';  // Añade un encabezado(Kit)
        /////////////
        echo "<tr><input class='boton_lin2red' type='button' onclick='javascript:eliminar_kit($row[kit])' value='Eliminar Kit'></tr>";
        echo "</br>";
        /////////////
        echo "<tr><input class='campo_texto' id='modelo' type=hidden value='$row[modelo]'></tr>";
        echo "<tr><input class='campo_texto' id='id_kit' type=hidden></tr>";
        // echo "<button class=boton_lin2 onclick=javascript:crear_kit()>Crear Kit</button>";

    }
    echo '<tr><td style=width:200px; align=center>', $row['pieza'], '</td><td align=center>', $row['descripcion'], '</td><td align=center>', $row['cantidad'], '</td>';  // display the row data
    ///En la linea 215 se imprime la cantidad sumada de la columna cantidad en tabla kit
    echo " <td align=center style=width:200px;>
   <input class='boton_lin2' type='button' id='guardar' onclick='javascript:mostrar_piezas($row[id_kit])' value='actualizar'>
   <input class='boton_lin2red' type='button' id='eliminar' onclick='javascript:eliminar($row[id_kit])' value='eliminar'>
    </td>
</tr>
    ";

    $tmp = $row['kit'];   //UPDATE $tmp!

}
if ($tmp !== null) {
    echo '</table>';  // Cierra el final de la tabla
}
?>
```

En teoría lo mando por js a otro documento y en este de borra y es donde supongo añadiría el codigo para hacer el update del campo kit

Archivo para borrar kit:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include('../coneccion.php');

if ($_SESSION['id_usuario'] != '') {


    $kit = $_GET['id'];
    $modelo = $_GET['modelo'];

    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `kit` WHERE `kit` = '$kit' AND `modelo` = '$modelo'");

    echo json_encode(1);
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo que justifique someter a la base de datos a esos constantes cambios? Muchas veces es mejor resolver este tipo de cosas desde una tabla externa que lleve el control de los kits (en caso de que sea realmente necesario). No sé, me parece un poco extraño este requerimiento, lo cual no significa que no tenga sentido... Uno de los problemas que veo es que si esa columna que modificas por ejemplo está indexada no conviene cambios constantes en esa columna. Además de eso, el mantenimiento es tedioso, y expone constantemente los datos a posibles errores.

Comment: O sea, si lo he entendido bien, ¿quieres resetear y reordenar todos los valores de `kit` cada vez que se elimine uno?  Si es así mi recomendación es que primero quizas deberias crearte un método que lo haga, y luego invocarlo cada vez que haces el delete.  Por lo tanto estudia la forma de hacerlo sin el delete, y cuando lo tengas controlado lo aplicas despues del delete.

Comment: El problema es no se como hacer ese método, el mayor problema es que existen modelos con sus propios kits y eso complica más las cosas,  he buscado en muchos foros y documentación y no he visto algo parecido como para poder estudiar y aplicarlo realmente, no estoy pidiendo que me resuelvan todo el codigo solo una recomendacion pequeña de que usar, soy bastante nuevo en esto asi que no conozco o he llegado a hacer cosas muy complicadas

Comment: No se, supongo que deberias consultar la base de datos con un select y sacar los campos id_kit y kit conjuntamente, luego almacenarlos en una matriz, y luego recorrerlos en orden de kit renumerandolos de nuevo con un contador de iteraciones y actualizando la base de datos en cada iteracion basandote en el id_kit como registro a actualizar en el where. ¿Algo asi no te parece bien?  Quizas es algo bruto, pero funcionaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que deberias consultar la base de datos con un `select` y sacar los campos `id_kit` y `kit` conjuntamente, para luego almacenarlos en un array, luego ordenar el array por su índice, que seria `kit`, y luego recorrerlos en orden de kit renumerandolos de nuevo con un contador de iteraciones y actualizando la base de datos en cada iteracion basandote en el `id_kit` como registro a actualizar en el where.

Es decir:

```
function resetearKit() {
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_kit, kit FROM kit");
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array_kits[$row['kit']][] = $row['id_kit'];
    }
    ksort($array_kits);
    $counter = 1;
    foreach(array_keys($array_kits) as $kitnumer) {
        foreach($array_kits[$kitnumer] as $id_kit) {
            $res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE kit SET kit = $counter WHERE id_kit = $id_kit");    
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Y llamar a esa función cada vez que ejecutas esto:

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `kit` WHERE `kit` = '$kit' AND `modelo` = '$modelo'");
resetearKit();
```

Lo he escrito a *ojímetro*, sin testearlo porque no tengo la tabla.

**¡¡Asegurate de probar el código en una tabla de pruebas!!**  No me hago responsable de nada :-)

Ya nos diras si algo asi te funciona y si has hecho modificaciones para corregir la respuesta, o tu mismo añadir la tuya.

Esta misma posible solución se podria optimizar obviando los kits que fueran menores que el registro suprimido, pero eso ya lo dejo a gusto del OP.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, solo hice un pequeño cambio muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro :-)  ¿El pequeño cambio era para adaptarlo mejor a tu entorno o porque tenia algun fallo mi código que se me habia pasado por alto algo?

Comment: Todo bien solo lo adapte a mi entorno pero funciona perfecto el codigo!

Comment: Gracias por responder, soy muy sensible y si me dicen que he hecho algo mal me hundo :-D